# visiting all nodes/subnodes of Ecore model generated by DSL

Tags: dsl, xtext, eclipse-emf-ecore

I know basics of xtext, and I have written a grammar(which works fine). I know that an Ecore model is generated. But I have problem in visiting all rules/sub-rules(nodes) of  grammar in AST (programmatically). 
Whenever I am applying some validation checks(or others) I always find it difficult to navigate to that particular rule on which check is to be applied. (to some extent I do it by hit and trail).

I want to ask that is there any way to print all the nodes sub-nodes of your grammar(programmatically) just to clarify in my mind how each node is being accessed.

Comment: Please be more precise! Are you iterating through the AST "by yourself" or, in case of validation, do you write an `@Check` method for each rule? Have you tried to get the `TreeIterator` from the resource?

Comment: at the moment I am using @Check method for rules in validation.
more precisely when ever I write new grammar, I am not been able differential between EClass, EAttributes, EReference etc.
I am not getting grip on them.

Comment: for example; I have this validation check;


@Check
def checkRegWithUnder(PointAddress pt) {
val s = pt.name.indexOf('_')

if (s!=0)
error("This name should start with an underscore",
SmcPackage::eINSTANCE.pointAddress_Name)
}


Why this only accept EAttribute? If I make changing in grammar, EAttributes will be changed. I want to on what basis they classify them as EAttribute EClass etc...

Comment: Have you had a look at glasses from your validators inheritence chain? I think there are several error methods. Maybe you'll find any accepting an EObject instead.